# In node.js (or asynchronous programming in general), what happens to the elements in the event loop when the thread crashes?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, reactive-programming, actor-model

I am currently reading about reactive programming and the actor model.

What I am wondering is : when asynchronous events (or messages) are triggered, some procedures of the program react to it, meaning they are queued in the event loop. In the context of a node.js web server, what happens when the thread crashes in the meantime (due to the handling of another request which throws)?

My understanding is that the elements in the event loop are lost. In this case, the preceding reactive workflows are stopped in the middle. But that would contradict with the fact that reactive programming, and/or the actor model, are seen as fault-tolerant and highly available systems.

Am I correct? I must be missing / not understanding something.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should not allow your thread to crash. You should handle the errors instead of crashing

Comment: Actually your thread can always crash; for unexpected errors. You handle the error you can anticipate, but your program can crash for so many reasons... Hence the "crash early" mantra. My question relates to theses cases (where we have unexpected / unanticipated errors)